# brms error with new R and R studio download

Tags: brms

I am new to posting in the stack overflow community so I am sorry if this the wrong place. I have recently downloaded the newest version of R (4.2.1.) and Rstudio (2022.07.1 Build 554). I was testing out an older previous document that knitted perfectly using the 'papaja' package and now a code chunk will not work (that worked previously) and provides this error message:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) :
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file425c5d805023.o:file425c5d805023.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev[_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file425c5d805023.o:file425c5d805023.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file425c5d805023.o:file425c5d805023.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x3a): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file425c5d805023.o:file425c5d805023.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection
```

I have the rtools42 and this worked with my previous version of R and Rstudio so I am not sure how to fix this. Help!

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with the compatibility of R4.2, RTools42 and Rstan. For me, it worked to install the preview of `rstan` 2.26.x:

Remove an existing rstan:

```
remove.packages("rstan")
if (file.exists(".RData")) file.remove(".RData")
```

Install preview version of packages:

```
install.packages("StanHeaders", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))
install.packages("rstan", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))
```

You can verify your installation with the example model:

```
example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)
```

References:

[rstan/wiki/Configuring-C---Toolchain-for-Windows](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Configuring-C---Toolchain-for-Windows)

[rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started)

[rstan-fit-error](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/rstan-fit-error-in-compilecode-f-code-language-language-verbose-verbose/20222/35)